# Using sqlite in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app and I want it to use sqlite. I followed a tutorial but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//add listener when device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db;
var dbex; // Hope it allows me to work with DB outside populateDB function

//function will be called when device ready
function onDeviceReady(){
    db = window.openDatabase("Test_DB", "1.0", "My DB for Test", 200000); //will create database Test_DB or open it
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuario (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nombre TEXT NOT NULL, Edad INTEGER NOT NULL, Email TEXT, Localidad TEXT, Pais TEXT NOT NULL)');

    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Datos (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, text_one TEXT, text_two TEXT, text_emg TEXT, color TEXT)');

    for (var i = 0; i > 4; i++) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Datos(text_one,text_two,text_emg, color) VALUES ("rouge", "vermelho", "-", "red")');
    }; //congruente
    dbex = tx;
}

//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    $("#siguiente").html('error');
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function successCB() {
    $("#siguiente").html('success');
    alert("success!");
    db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
}

//select all from Usuario
function queryDB(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Usuario',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
}

var pinchado = document.getElementById("registro");

pinchado.disabled = true;

pinchado.onclick = function(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    var edad = document.getElementById("edad");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var localidad = document.getElementById("localidad");
    var pais = document.getElementById("pais");
    dbex.executeSql('INSERT INTO Usuario(Nombre,Edad,Email,Localidad,Pais) VALUES (nombre.value,edad.value,email.value,localidad.value,pais.value)');

    function querySuccess(tx,result){
        console.log("querySuccess")
        $("#siguiente").html('result');
    }
}

function doCheck(){
    var allFilled = true;

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].value == ''){
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    pinchado.disabled = !allFilled;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == "text"){
            inputs[i].onkeyup = doCheck;
            inputs[i].onblur = doCheck;
        }
    }
};
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'executeSql' of undefined index.html:134
  pinchado.onclick
```

Any ideas?

Comment: just comment  dbex.executeSql('I line and check whether prblm s related to that line, did u got successCB or errorCB ?

Comment: Actually, I didn't get any of them, that's weird

Comment: I tried running your code in my Chrome desktop browser, and the database was created successfully.  However in successCB, queryDB is referenced in your code, but couldn't be found. (It's possible you just omitted it from SO).  Are you developing for Android or iOS?  If iOS, use Safari's remote web debugger, and mess around in the console to see if the db is actually being created.

Comment: Thanks @njtman, I'm developing for both android and iOs, I'll check again. Just one question: English is not my mother tongue, so, what does SO stand for? (google is not helping here)

Comment: @Sascuash SO is Stack Overflow.  I was saying maybe you omitted some of your code on your Stack Overflow posting, because the queryDB variable referenced inside the successCB was not found.  Maybe this is the reason your code is failing, or maybe it exists, but you just didn't include it on your SO posting.

Comment: Ok, well, I didn't post all my code, as I create about 7 tables and ask for a lot of data to the user, but I might have missed something, so I'll check and edit my question so it doesn't miss anithing

Comment: Now you can see the script (I only ommited creation of some tables)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `db=window.openDatabase()` inside `onDeviceReady()` so that the variable `db` gets initialized correctly.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    db=window.openDatabase("Trial_DB", "1.0", "My DB for Test", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Comment: Still get the error, but it was a nice try. You know if testing from pc browser has something to do with this problem?

Comment: Looks like the usage of `dbex.executeSql` inside `pinchado.onclick` is not correct. Can you use `db.transaction`? e.g. `db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql(...);});`